# Cascade circuit

Tags: converter

To power a PA107DP Apex Microtechnology amplifier, I need two power supplies, one of + / -18V and another of + / -100V.

[image]

To supply it with +/- 100V, I use the R24100B power supply from Recom.

In the datasheet I saw the configuration of two cascade converters.

When do we use this configuration?

[image]

This converter is used on this schematic:

[image]

Why do they use two power supplies (R24-100B) in cascade?

Answer (score 0):

It's just showing you how you can use two units to double the voltage range from the same input supply. This is a unique feature of fully isolated power supplies.

Comment: it is not to have + vout and -vout? (dual output)

Comment: It can do that as well.

Comment: Not in the configuration that is shown. But as indicated by @BrianDrummond, if you take a wire from the Com of the top regulator and reference that to your circuit ground, you'll have a bipolar supply.